# Is there a CSS method to fill a custom shape upon hover?

Tags: html, css, sass

Working on this CSS challenge. I was able to get the buttons to look the way it's supposed to, but I was wondering if there's some way to have the hover background color fit within the space of the arrows? I was looking into the fill method, but didn't think it would work as it's not svg.

https://codepen.io/al2613/pen/xYXPvB

```
$primary-color: adjust-hue(MediumAquamarine, 13);
$primary-accent: PeachPuff;
$default-font: "Delius", sans-serif;

body {
background-color: $primary-color;
font-family: $default-font;
}

h1 {
border-bottom: 1px solid $primary-accent;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
}

.container {
max-width: 600px;
margin: auto;
background: white;
padding: 20px 30px;
margin-top: 50px;
border-radius: 30px 0 /30px 60px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px darken($primary-color, 11);
}

.button-group {
text-align: center;
width: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: none;
position: relative;

   .button-with-arrow {
      height: 35px;
      position: relative;
      width: 110px;
      background-color: $primary-accent;
      border: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: -2px;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;
    }

     button:nth-child(-n+2)::after {
     position: absolute;
     border-right: 2px solid white;
     border-bottom: 2px solid white;
     content: "";
     width: 100px;
     height: 35px;
     right: -2px;
     top: 22px;
     transform: rotate(-45deg)
   }
    button:hover{
    background-color: darken( $primary-accent, 13%);
    transition: 0.3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Before asking question Just do little research Please!!!  look at [this example](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/xRmmdr)

Comment: masks, clip-path... or even just go old school and use the classic way to draw triangles on CSS with borders on the after and before pseudo-elements. Which is probably what the challenge is intending. That approach should make it not only IE 11 compatible, but even down to IE8.

Comment: @RajnishRajput - now that you have condescended OP, can you share with her how to convert your reference to her requirements? Notice that her challenge lacks the `li > a` structure and thus does not have access to the parent (`li`) elements pseudo-elements.

Comment: @Forty3 surly OP's challenge isn't a challenge. Its just a wrong architecture for what she's want to achieve. why she took `button` for that but after all she can use buttons inside `li` and if anyone think that button will not work then she can use `buttons` instead of `li` and `span` instead of `a` only if she want to make it easier for her...... and let newbie do some effort, I believe they can learn better by there-self :)

Comment: A fair point, @RajnishRajput. I struggled and couldn't figure out how to do it using the `<button>` structure OP was provided.

Comment: appreciate you guys' help. im not allowed to change the html markup as per the challenge but i've been playing around with clip path which seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: @Annette Lin if you are not able to change HTML will give you solution soon, next time mention everything, and surely will help you :) ..... Until then look at my example and try to do that in your HTML, .... Everything is fair in your code just try to make that arrow like my example :)

Comment: thanks! i ended up using the clip method. probably not the best CSS lol i'm always open to hearing methods of improvement! https://codepen.io/al2613/pen/zRPdYL

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to tweak the `before` pesudo element and adjust its `background-color` while hover of the `button`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/oEoyxz?editors=1100)

Please let me know whether this helps.

Comment: thank you! that was super helpful. i ended up using clip method and it worked out well in the end.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may post your answer and upvote and/or choose the answer as correct so that it would help other users. Thank you.